# How to create a new column resulting from two columns present in other tables

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, dbt

Here are my 2 dbt models:
tbstg_test_article_family :

```
WITH article_family_check AS (
    SELECT
        a.article AS article_number,
        b.article_family AS article_family,
        CASE
            WHEN article_family IS NULL THEN 'Article Family must not be empty'
            ELSE NULL
        END AS business_rule
    FROM bigqueryproject.projectdataset.table AS a
    JOIN {{ ref('tbsd_mara') }} AS b
        ON a.article = b.article
)

SELECT
    article_number,
    article_family,
    CASE
        WHEN business_rule IS NOT NULL THEN 'FAIL'
        ELSE 'PASS'
    END AS test_status, business_rule
FROM article_family_check
```

tbstg_test_article_number :

```
WITH article_number_check AS (
    SELECT article AS article_number,
        CASE
            WHEN LENGTH(article) != 10 AND NOT STARTS_WITH(article, 'VC')
            THEN 'Article Number must be 10 characters long and start with VC'
            WHEN LENGTH(article) != 10 THEN 'Article Number must be 10 characters long'
            WHEN NOT STARTS_WITH(article, 'VC') THEN 'Article Number must start with VC'
            ELSE NULL
        END AS business_rule
    FROM bigqueryproject.projectdataset.table
)

SELECT article_number,
    CASE
        WHEN business_rule IS NOT NULL THEN 'FAIL'
        ELSE 'PASS'
    END AS test_status, business_rule
FROM article_number_check
```

I would like to make a third dbt model which looks like the following schema but I have difficulty writing the SQL code.

[image]

Comment: That looks like a union. Just add a new column with the name as a literal value and use `union all` to get them in one result. To use two CTEs in a single query: `with q1 as (...), q2 as (...) select ... from q1 union all select ... from q2`

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I've made a third model which UNION ALL (UNION doesn't work in BigQuery SQL) my two models

Answer (score 0):

## Option 1: Using raw SQL

```
SELECT
  article_number, test_status, business_rule, "test_article_family" as test_name
FROM
  {{ ref('tbstg_test_article_family')}}

 UNION

SELECT
  article_number, test_status, business_rule, "test_article_number" as test_name
FROM
  {{ ref('tbstg_test_article_number')}}
```

## Option 2: Using dbt_utils

[union_relations](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-utils?tab=readme-ov-file#union_relations-source) of dbt_utils can be used. There's a drawback that `test_name` will be the name of the source table.

```
{{ dbt_utils.union_relations(
  relations=[ref('tbstg_test_article_family'), ref('tbstg_test_article_number')],
  source_column_name =["test_name"]
) }}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I've made a third model which UNION ALL (UNION doesn't work in BigQuery SQL) my two models

Comment: `dbt_utils.union_relation` is actually doing a `UNION ALL`.